# How do I stop Android app from crashin on resume?

Tags: android

I am trying to make my game multitask friendly, however whenever the screen is turned off and turned back on, or the game is navigated away from and back to, I get a null pointer exception pointing to this part of the code:

`GLES20.glUniformMatrix3fv(mTextureMatrixHandle, 1, false, render.mTexMatrix, 0);`

I don't have anything apart from super.onResume(); and mGLSurfaceView.onResume(); for the onResume() method and the same for onPause(), except with onPause rather than onResume. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I imagine `render` is `null`. That'd be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that the objects are re-created when the activity is started again. Where are those variables initialized? Typical case for this kind error is when you store objects in a global variables. When the activity is created again, they are null.

So: check which of mTextureMatrixHandle, render, or render.mTexMatrix is null. Re-create it if it is null.

In general, you should not rely on any data being restored at activity creation. So don't use global variables, and rely only on data passed via the intent. If you really want to use global data, you should be aware that it may be reset, and re-create it when needed.

Comment: So rather than having things initialized in the constructor, it should be done in the onCreate method?

Comment: That should not make a difference, since the constructor is called each time an activity is created. Parameters should be passed via an intent, and read in onCreate. If you wish to memorize the state of your activity so that it is restored when it is resumed, you can use the savedInstanceState Bundle.

Comment: Oh, I realized my error. I created things on the onSurfaceChanged, since I intended it to only be run once. However it was run again since I restarted the app. I have set it so that it is now only run once. Thanks.